# PrintingPermissionLevel, SafePrinting, and restrictions

Tags: c#, .net, printing

There is a [PrintingPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printingpermission.aspx) attribute in the framework which takes a [PrintingPermissionLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printingpermissionlevel.aspx) enumeration with one of these values;

- **NoPrinting:** Prevents access to printers. NoPrinting is a subset of SafePrinting.
- **SafePrinting:** Provides printing only from a restricted dialog box. SafePrinting is a subset of DefaultPrinting.
- **DefaultPrinting:** Provides printing programmatically to the default printer, along with safe printing through semirestricted dialog box. DefaultPrinting is a subset of AllPrinting.
- **AllPrinting:** Provides full access to all printers.

The documentation is really sparse, and I wondered if anyone can tell me more about the `SafePrinting` option. What does the documentation mean when it says *"Provides printing only from a restricted dialog box."* I have no idea what this means. Can anyone shed any light?

This subject is touched in the MS certification [70-505: TS: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, Windows Forms Application Development](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-505&Locale=en-us) and so I'm keen to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this actually implemented anywhere when peeking with Reflector.  There is only one print dialog ever used, both by WF and WPF, the native Windows print dialog.  It doesn't have a restricted version.

Printing support in .NET has been a bit cumbersome, it took a while before the System.Printing namespace became available.  There might well have been early plans to implement a "better" print dialog, plans that didn't pan out.

I would guess that the exam question was more focused on testing understanding of CAS rather than very obscure details about the actual meaning of a specific CAS attribute.

Comment: Thanks; I appreciate your efforts. 

The exams can be pretty... petty, sometimes. They'll check crappy little details like that. But I'm glad it doesn't do anything. I just have to remember that CAS _thinks_ it does ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the 70-505 MCTS training book:

- AllPrinting provides unrestricted access to the printer
- DefaultPrinting enables programmatic printing to the default printer and access to other printers through a printer dialog box.
- SafePrinting allows printing only through a printer dialog box.
- NoPrinting - pretty self-explanatory.

So, SafePrinting stops you printing programmatically without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

A restricted PrintDialog box refers to the various properties of the PrintDialog that can be set such as AllowSomePages,AllowSelection,AllowCurrentPage,PrintToFile etc.